# Why does points not change to the users score and instead remains as the temporary value of 0?

Tags: python

```
points = "temp"
a = "temp"
f = "temp"

def pointincrementer():
  global points
  points = 0
  for line in f:
    for word in a:
      if word in line:
        scorelen = int(len(user+","))
        scoreval = line[0:scorelen]
        isolatedscore = line.replace(scoreval,'')
        if "," in  line:
          scorestr = isolatedscore.replace(",","")
          score = int(scorestr)
          points = score + 1
          print(points)

def score2():
  f = open('test.txt','r')
  a = [user]
  lst = []
  for line in f:
    for word in a:
      if word in line:
        pointincrementer()
        print(points)
        point = str(points)
        winning = (user+","+point+","+"\n")
        line = line.replace(line,winning)
    lst.append(line)
  f.close()
  f = open('test.txt','w')
  for line in lst:
    f.write(line)
  f.close()
  print("Points updated")


user = input("Enter username: ") #change so user = winners userid
with open('test.txt') as myfile:
  if user in myfile.read():
    score2()
  else:
    f = open('test.txt','r')
    f2 = f.read()
    f3 = (f2+"\n"+user)
    f.close()
    f = open('test.txt','w')
    f.write(f3)
    f.close()
    score2()
```

This is paired with `test.txt`, which looks like this:

```
one,1,
two,5,
three,4,
four,94,
```

When this code is run, it it will ask the user their name (as expected) and then will print `0` (when it should instead print the user's score) and then `Points updated`. Anybody know how to sort this out?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Using global variables in a function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423379/using-global-variables-in-a-function)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are many problems with your code.  You should not be using global variables like that.  Each function should be passed what it needs, do its computing, and return values for the caller to handle.  You should not be reading the file multiple times.  And you can't write the file while you still have it open with the `with` statement.

Here, I read the file at the beginning into a Python dictionary.  The code just updates the dictionary, then writes it back out at the end.  This makes for a simpler and more maintainable structure.

```
def readdata(fn):
    data = {}
    for row in open(fn):
        info = row.strip().split(',')
        data[info[0]] =  int(info[1])
    return data

def writedata(fn,data):
    f = open(fn,'w')
    for k,v in data.items():
        print( f"{k},{v}", file=f )

def pointincrementer(data,user):
    return data[user] + 1

def score2(data, user):
    points = pointincrementer(data, user)
    print(points)
    data[user] = points
    print("Points updated")

user = input("Enter username: ")

data = readdata( 'test.txt' )
if user not in data:
    data[user] = 0

score2(data, user)
writedata( 'test.txt', data )
```

Comment: I appreciate this effort, my coding skills as you saw are all over the place. Although this didnt add new users, i can easily add that. Thankyou for your help man :)

Comment: Yes, my code absolutely DOES add new users.  That's the `if user not in data:` section.

Comment: when i added it to the whole code, it didnt. Thats just an observation and i already edited it so it would work. Thanks again

Answer (score 1):

The `f` in `pointincrementer()` refers to the `"temp"` string declared on the third line. The `f` in `score2()` refers to the file handle declared immediately below the function header. To get around this, you can pass the file handle into `pointincrementer()`:

```py
def pointincrementer(file_handle):
  global points
  points = 0
  for line in file_handle:
    for word in a:
      if word in line:
        scorelen = int(len(user+","))
        scoreval = line[0:scorelen]
        isolatedscore = line.replace(scoreval,'')
        if "," in  line:
          scorestr = isolatedscore.replace(",","")
          score = int(scorestr)
          points = score + 1
          print(points)

def score2():
  file_handle = open('test.txt','r')
  a = [user]
  lst = []
  for line in f:
    print(line)
    for word in a:
      if word in line:
        pointincrementer(file_handle)
        print(points)
        point = str(points)
        winning = (user+","+point+","+"\n")
        line = line.replace(line,winning)
    lst.append(line)
  f.close()
  f = open('test.txt','w')
  for line in lst:
    f.write(line)
  f.close()
  print("Points updated")
```

This leads to a parsing error. However, as you haven't described what each function is supposed to do, this is the limit to which I can help. (The code is also extremely difficult to read -- the lack of readability in this code snippet is likely what caused this issue.)